# Bijection but not diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined as $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}, & \text{if }x\neq 0 \\
0, & \text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}$$
I want to prove the following:

1. there are neighborhoods $U$ of $0$ and $V$ of $0$ such that $f:U\to V$ is a bijection.
2. there is no neighborhood of $0$ where the function $f$ is diffeomorphism.

**My approach:** I think that it should be not so difficult but I am missing something.
First of all, one can show that $$f'(x) =
\begin{cases}
1+2x\sin \frac{1}{x}-\cos \frac{1}{x}, & \text{if }x\neq 0 \\
1, & \text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}$$ Also $f'(\frac{1}{2\pi n})=0$, i.e, one can find arbitrary small zero of $f'$.

I am wondering can anyone answer my questions?
Thank you!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/691328/72031

Comment: The function is not a bijection in any neighborhood of $0$ as a continuous bijection must be strictly monotone.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, many thanks for your link! But I think that I have a simpler proof. I've uploaded it. Please take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I've already showed that $f'(\frac{1}{2\pi n})=0$ for each $n\geq 1$. One can check that $f''(\frac{1}{2\pi n})\neq0$. Indeed, for $x\neq 0$, we have $f''(x)=(2-\frac{1}{x^2})\sin \frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x}\cos \frac{1}{x}$ and hence $f''(\frac{1}{2\pi n})=-4\pi n$.
Hence $\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ is a local extrema.

Suppose that there are nbhds $U$ and $V$ of $0$ such that $f:U\to V$ is a bijection. Since $f$ is continuous on $U$, then $f$ is strictly monotone on $U$. However, $\exists N$ such that $\frac{1}{2\pi N}\in U$ and since $\frac{1}{2\pi N}$ is a local extrema, then we have a contradiction.